# send email to email field in specific content type content creation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7. I can't find out how to send mail to email field in specific content type content created. like, someone create content and fill out email field in that content, then site should send email notification to that email field.  Is it possible? I've research Rules but with Rules basic function can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this can be done using rule, you just need to use the replacement pattern there in rules action, all the fields value are available there like [node:title] for title of  the node and [node:body] for the body of the node, similarly something must be avaiable for your email field, you just need to put that replacement string in the "To value" in rules action.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if i am right, you want to send an email if new content was created?
I don't have experience with "Rules" but you could build your own custom module for that.
You only need to hook into all events you might need for that.

For example:
hook_insert: Respond to creation of a new node

This requires basic understanding of Drupal Module System.

Complete List of Hooks: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7
Module developer's guide: http://drupal.org/developing/modules

Greetings.